# How we can create the folder in google drive by using java

Tags: java, google-drive-api, google-docs, google-drive-realtime-api

I need to create the folder in Google drive by using Java. Does any one tell me the example or how to create the folder in Google drive. Thanks in advance...!!!

My program

```
package net.sf.dynamicreports.examples;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import com.google.gson.JsonObject;

public class SourceCodeProgram {

    public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception {
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(
                "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files");
        post.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        post.addHeader("Authorization",
                "Bearer  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX ");

        JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
        jsonObject.addProperty("title", "Test folder");
        jsonObject
                .addProperty("mimeType", "application/vnd.google-apps.folder");

        post.setEntity(new StringEntity(jsonObject.toString()));
        httpClient.execute(post);
    }
}
```

In above program everything is going fine just want to know about the

post.addHeader("Authorization",
                "Bearer  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX ");

What should i place at

> XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

is it some kind of key which will i get from google?

Comment: Have you google it? https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/folder

Comment: @RubioRic yes already i write one program for that please see in question i update it

Comment: @RubioRic  is something wrong in above program?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: It is your program. You should tell us what it does?!

Comment: @GhostCat actually while searching on this site i get the above program but just want to know   **post.addHeader("Authorization",
                "Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");** what  should I write behlf of XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX?

Comment: Use this [Drive API JAVA Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/java) instead and start from there. The 'xxxxxxxx' is not something you can copy and paste from somewhere. It is an access token generated by Google API. But for testing purposes, you can generate it from OAuthplayground, copy and paste in place of xxxxx. It will only last an hour so you also need to implement refresh tokens. Again that's for testing purposes only.

Answer (score 0):

Google uses OAuth 2.0 authentication, you need to add OAuth Token in place of xxxxxxxx for OAuth 2.0 authentication (Authorization Bearer header is used for OAuth authentication purpose). This may be useful for you : https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2

After successful authentication with Google, you can use following code for creating the folder in Google Drive:

```
File fileMetadata = new File();
fileMetadata.setName("Invoices");
fileMetadata.setMimeType("application/vnd.google-apps.folder");

File file = driveService.files().create(fileMetadata).setFields("id").execute();
System.out.println("Folder ID: " + file.getId());
```

P.S. - This is referenced from [Google Drive Help Link](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/folder)

Comment: From where I can get the OAuth Token or how can we create it ?

Comment: You can take help from following link to get the token : https://github.com/burnash/gspread/wiki/How-to-get-OAuth-access-token-in-console%3F                https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2

Comment: This link is also useful : https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#offline

Answer (score 0):

Use this [Drive API JAVA Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/java) instead and start from there. The 'xxxxxxxx' is not something you can copy and paste from somewhere. It is an access token generated by Google API. But for testing purposes, you can generate it from OAuthplayground, copy and paste in place of xxxxx. It will only last an hour so you also need to implement refresh tokens. Again that's for testing purposes only.

To give you an idea of the access token being generated, you can see a Javascript implementation of this in [Picker API](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/):

```
function onAuthApiLoad() {
        window.gapi.auth.authorize(
            {
              'client_id': clientId,
              'scope': scope,
              'immediate': false
            },
            handleAuthResult);
      }

 function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
        if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
          oauthToken = authResult.access_token; //<-- access token 
          createPicker();
        }
      }
```