# Android Access Token for Google Drive Api to download a file

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, access-token, google-drive-android-api

To download a file from google drive according to [this](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads) we have to use

GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/0B9jNhSvVjoIVM3dKcGRKRmVIOVU?alt=media
Authorization: Bearer 'ACCESS_TOKEN'

I want to know what exactly this access token is?
is this android client id? when passing client id in Authorization header yet it gives 401 un authorized error.
and if I Use below given code, file is downloaded successfully but when I try to open it, it says invalid file

```
OutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
driveService.files().get(fileId)
    .executeMediaAndDownloadTo(outputStream);
```

Comment: you do not have to emulate the client, while one can add it with gradle ...

Comment: @MartinZeitler what to do? 
Do we need to add something to manifest file..?

Comment: Did you add dependencies into .gradle file?

Comment: @NaveedAli added the dependencies below. hope it's all.

Comment: Yes i have added dependencies... yet I will confirm

Comment: for testing purposes you can generate an access token from Google OAuthplayground which grants you 1 hour access token. In production, that is generated by Google OAuth API.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the [Drive API Client Library for Java](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/drive/v3) into the module's `build.gradle`... instead of creating a whole new client for the 
Google Drive REST API. The clientId should then come from the `google-services.json` file (and might differ from the REST credentials, check the console).

`dependencies {`

`//` [Google HTTP Client](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.http-client):

```
compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-android:1.22.0'
compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson2:1.22.0'
```

`//` [Google  API Client](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.api-client):

```
compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.22.0'
compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-jackson2:1.22.0'
```

`//` [Google OAuth Client](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.oauth-client):

```
compile 'com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client:1.22.0'
```

`//` [Google Drive API](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.apis):

```
compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v3-rev65-1.22.0'
```

`}`

then run `./gradlew clean` to download the libraries.

Comment: Is access token, client id??

Comment: @NaveedAli there is a dependency for Google OAuth client ... so you probably won't need to worry about this. to create a REST client for Android is complete non-sense, while there is a ready-made Java client for Android... just use that and try to create web-applications for Android.

Comment: @ Naveed Ali   access token is not client id, check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46065286/6143482).

Comment: @noogui you guys all seem to mess up the different API available to access Google Drive... your JavaScript is irrelevant to a Java question. http://www.bubblecode.net/en/2016/01/22/understanding-oauth2/ ...while on Android one does not have to code anything of that from scratch, because there is a `google-oauth-client`. the solution approach is fundamentally botched, while using the (wrong) REST API.

Comment: @MartinZeitler you are correct. i was just pointing out that it's not a 'client id' that you can copy paste from you google dev console., again, you're correct :) the JS sample was just meant to demo the process like that in Java google oauth client

Comment: @noogui on Android it's rather alike https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start (one just drops one file into the project, which holds all kinds of credentials) - while the library takes care of access & refresh tokens.

Answer (score 0):

After reading [this](http://Mobile%20API%20Security) article I came to know what is access token exactly
[Mobile Api Security](https://stormpath.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-mobile-api-security)

In OAuth2 for Mobile API Security

1. A user opens up your mobile app and is prompted for their username or email and password.
2. You send a POST request from your mobile app to your API service with the user’s username or email and password data included (OVER SSL!).
3. You validate the user credentials, and create an access token for the user that expires after a certain amount of time.
4. You store this access token on the mobile device, treating it like an API key which lets you access your API service.
5. Once the access token expires and no longer works, you re-prompt the user for their username or email and passwordU.

Comment: you get an access token and then need to obtain a refresh token... while you are totally reinventing the wheel, which is not required on Android, at all. won't down-vote, while the approach is just pointless. why you waste your time to write a client, which not works - while there is a client, which works and is being actively maintained? just accept the answer above and have it working soon... did you even try it?

Comment: brother I left this task in pending because I was shifted to an other project..
I was not clear about access token thats why I asked that question but now with the help of mentioned article it is clear now..
I upvoted your answer.. the issue was occuring even I tried your lines.. thats why i could not acccept it... now I dont have enough time to come back to this task..
therefore I cant accept your answer sorry for that :)

Comment: you'll obviously have to use the loaded library's classes instead of your code. here's the docs: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/drive/v3 - it's oAuth2 implementation is explained here: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/oauth2